Jquery/HTML: Empty new line <textarea> is not preserved in <pre> with text()
When I take the value of a textarea with jQuery and put that in a <pre> with .text(), it does not preserve the last empty new line.
If I put it in another textarea with .val(), it does preserve it.

I tried applying 'whitespace:pre-wrap' on input <textarea> and output <pre> with CSS, but that didn't do anything.
Then I tried the following str.replace before adding it with .text() and that magically worked:
$('#output3').text(val.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '\n\r'));

But, when I try the logical order '\r\n' instead of '\n\r' in the replace, it does not work.
Here's a fiddle.
Now, I can just go with the above replace() that works, but I want to know why this is happening.

You might be unhappy with the closing of your question with a duplicate that seems somewhat unrelated. Regrettably this happens a lot. The duplicate is, of course, not completely unrelated, but somewhat unsatisfactory. There is a better answer possible in this case, and I was writing it when your question was closed. In short: text() and html() run your input through the HTML parser, which is build into the browser. It always normalize newlines, and thus strips leading and trailing ASCII whitespace.

It's not the full explanation I was writing, but this has to do. I'm not going to repeat all the steps I was to mention in my answer here. I think you should be able to work it out now?

You don't want to know how often I've spent half an hour researching, and writing an answer, only to find the dreaded: "this question does not accept answers", message at the top of the page. I enjoy the process, and that's the only reason I keep falling for this, but answering questions on Stack Overflow, in depth, should never be your goal.

@KIKOSoftware you can share a fiddle link to support, (in case you want)

@Death-is-the-real-truth: There's nothing to fiddle here, the explanation is in my first comment.

@KIKOSoftware A bit silly the question is closed, my question was also why replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '\n\r') created the desired result and replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '\r\n') not, but, oh well. I can't be bothered editing it to point that out.
As I read here in the comments and on the 'duplicate' question it's a matter of 'it is what it is'.
What I will do is count the actual line breaks the user gives in and have my script add those accordingly. I will cross browser test my 'hack' and then just go with that.
